# Sequelize magic method not found using Express and Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, magic-methods

I'm coding an application using Sequelize, Express and Node.JS; after set a OneToMany relationship between User and Product, just like this:

app.js:

```
Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
User.hasMany(Product);
```

and from a controller called admin.js I'm trying to create a new Product using a magic method:

admin.js:

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  req.user.createProduct({
    title: title,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    price: price,
    description: description
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("Record successfully created");
      return res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

postAddProduct is triggered after submit a form, the error I'm getting is this:

[image: error]

So, my question is: based on sequelize's official documentation, after define a relationship I can use methods for create, edit o search an entity, what am I missing to get access to these methods?

thanks for your comments

Comment: is `req.user` sequelize model instance?

Comment: console.log(req,user), and, share its log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though my model is called Product, the table's name is newproducts, so, in order to solve this I made this change:

```
req.user.createNewproduct({
    title: title,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    price: price,
    description: description   })
```

After this, problem solved

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see someone else taking [Max's Node.js course!](https://www.udemy.com/course/nodejs-the-complete-guide/)

I had this same problem. For me, it stemmed from the fact that I defined how my `id` column works differently. Instead of this...

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
},
```

...I did this...

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
},
```

and utilized the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package to make unique Product and User IDs. Because of this, I had to update how I defined my SQL relations in `app.js`:

```
Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
User.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: "id" });
```

So if you're using a custom ID generator or something, make sure to specify that you are in the `options` object and the function should appear!

You can read more about this in the docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#defining-the-sequelize-associations

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set to request argument **user[0]** instead of **user** (sequelize v6.35.2)

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    User
       .findAll({where: {id: 1}})
       .then((user) => {
          req.user = user[0];
          next();
       })
       .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
User.hasMany(Product);

exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  req.user.createProduct({
    title: title,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    price: price,
    description: description
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("Record successfully created");
      return res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```